# Nativescript NFC between two phones

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, nativescript

I just learnt about NFC and the possibility to exchange data by placing phones next to each other, I want to know if its possible to transmit data between twophones via NFC with nativescript.

My app flow is like this:

User places his phone next to my tablet or my phone, my phone receives the other phone user id and performs an axios call with id as payload, pretty simple right? but is it doable in nativescript?

I'm using Nativescript-vue.

Comment: {N} provides a JavaScript runtime, enables you to write your native app in JavaScript. There are no limitations in accessing any device / third party APIs. So it's very much possible to do almost everything you could do in native Android / iOS. You can find the plugins for NFC and Bluetooth in market place, if you find a specific feature missing you can still access the native APIs directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about it in Nativescript but in Java you can but you should not.

Android Beam (The term of NFC Device to NFC Device) is deprecated in API 29 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage(android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...)  and most likely removed/not supported in Android 11

The reason given for removing it was that it is too slow and too unreliable (Which I found it was when trying to use it)

The distance is also very small, the two devices would need to be placed back to back.

The replacement is supposed to be Bluetooth/Wifi based but it has not been released yet.

Also add there is still away to it with Android even if Android Beam goes away, as they will still support NFC card emulation (So one phone emulates an NFC card and the other reads it as if it were a NFC card). This will still be supported BUT you need to do a lot of low level coding and I don't know it Nativescript would support that (A quick look at NFC Plugin and the answer is No, NativeScript does not support NFC very well and does not event Support Android Beam)

I think the same goes with Bluetooth, technically possible and possible in Java BUT Nativescript does not support Bluetooth to the level needed (Again it really only support reading and writing to other devices, it does not support emulating a device itself).

You could of course write your own plugins, but then you would have write the Java for Android and iOS as well as the plugin interface.

Also Should be possible to use WiFi Direct https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct but again using you have to use native API's

Comment: I see, is it possible to do what I wrote with bluetooth as by today?, so instead of phones touching just have both phones enable bluetooth and userA send ID to user B.

Comment: Updated answer with bluetooth and wifi answers